# JMeter external list of variables to ignore in a ForEach

Tags: jmeter

I am working on a cleanup script for a webpage with children webpages.  Some of the children need to have cleanup actions on them while others need to be ignored.  Need some advice on what would be the best way to do this?  Right now, I am using an If Controller with an expression like:

```
${__groovy(vars.get("subwebpage") != "Webpage to ignore pagename" && 
vars.get("subwebpage") != "Webpage 2 Ignore pagename" )}
```

But, I would like to have the list of webpages to ignore in some external file instead of some huge If expression.

Current Test plan structure:

- HTTP get child webpages

  - JSON extract child webpages
- ForEach child webpage

  - If child webpage not one of the values(groovy above)

    - HTTP do some clean up stuff

Comment: Are you just trying to simplify the if condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amend your [If Controller's](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) condition to use the following [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black):

```
${__groovy(!new File('myFile.txt').readLines().contains(vars.get('subwebpage')),)}
```

It will execute child sampler **only** if `myFile.txt` will **not contain** the `${subwebpage}` JMeter Variable value.